# Python mesa visualisation page not loading in PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am using the python library mesa which includes the visualization tool JupyterViz. The visualization page is not loading in PyCharm, I don't receive any errors.

The example code (from mesa tutorial):

```
from mesa.experimental import JupyterViz

page = JupyterViz(
    BoltzmannWealthModel,
    model_params,
    measures=["Gini"],
    name="Money Model",
    agent_portrayal=agent_portrayal,
)
# This is required to render the visualization in the Jupyter notebook
page
```

In Google Colab it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3JY8.png)

And in PyCharm it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXprS.png)

I am using macOS 13.6.1 on an Intel-Chip MacBook, python 3.11 and PyCharm 2023.2.3 (Professional Edition).